# what does gitolite setup fix?

Tags: githooks, gitolite

gitolite info didn't work, adding keys turned them into a `no access` key and did NOT create a corresponding entry in auth-keys file.

**To fix this run `gitolite setup` on gitolite server**

### Question: what could have landed me in that mess?

And what does `gitolite setup` do when invoked for the n-th time (it's no longer setting things up, according to the docs it fixes hooks, but I wonder what the use case would be and which was mine)?

### More details on gitolite info

gitolite info command is invoked like so:

```
> ssh git-user@ser-git
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello git-admin, this is ...@... running gitolite3 3.6.7-2 (Debian) on git 2.17.1

 R W    some-repository
 R W    gitolite-admin
 R W    testing
Connection to ser-git closed.
```

Bad output is: `FATAL: unknown git/gitolite command: 'info'`

### More details: keys without access.

`gitolite sshkeys-lint` was showing keys with `(no access)`, now those keys have access as I set them (now meaning after `gitolite setup`).

`ssh-keygen -lf /home/repo/.ssh/authorized_keys | wc -l` (or without piped part, regardless) number of keys and their names indicated I didn't have the newest one added.

Similar question that did not work for me: [keydir entries not propagating to authorized_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149802/keydir-entries-not-propagating-to-authorized-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs pretty much had the answer once I dug deeper, I guess. Which is fairly nice of @sitaramc.

> - Without options, 'gitolite setup' is a general "fix up everything" command
>     (for example, if you brought in repos from outside, or someone messed
>     around with the hooks, or you made an rc file change that affects access
>     rules, etc.)

Symptoms keys stopped propagating and error `FATAL: unknown git/gitolite command: 'info'` on `ssh git-user@ser-git`. Fix was to run `gitolite setup`. So onto first question, the title one:

### what does gitolite setup fix?

1. `gitolite setup` is implemented [here](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4191404225e1b86534392f0fdbeb5b766bb0f45d/src/lib/Gitolite/Setup.pm)
2. my Perl is rather weak, but there's a setup function in [line 56](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4191404225e1b86534392f0fdbeb5b766bb0f45d/src/lib/Gitolite/Setup.pm#L56). It calls args (which parses options, so here it had nothing to parse), then unless `h_only` (hooks only arg for setup), which wasn't used, so we skip `compile` and `POST_COMPILE` trigger and go for the hooks.

   sub setup {
       my ( $admin, $pubkey, $h_only, $message ) = args();

   ```
   unless ($h_only) {
       setup_glrc();
       setup_gladmin( $admin, $pubkey, $message );

       _system("gitolite compile");
       _system("gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE");
   }

   hook_repos();    # all of them, just to be sure
   ```

   }
3. package `Gitolite::conf::store` has `hook_repos()`, [line 228](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4191404225e1b86534392f0fdbeb5b766bb0f45d/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm#L228): we change the dir to repo base dir (as per config file), and for each phy_repo we do `hook_1(phy_repo)`. What is a phy_repo? *a phy*sical one.
4. same package, different method and line: [`hook_1($repo)` in line 354](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4191404225e1b86534392f0fdbeb5b766bb0f45d/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm#L354).

#### Method `hook_1($repo)`

It's quite literally about fixing all the hooks.

1. Recreates dirs for common and admin hooks.
2. Rewrites update_hook (common) and post_update_hook (admin).
3. Sets 755 permissions for both common and admin hooks.
4. Then using `ln_sf` it symlinks the folders for common/admin hooks.
5. `ln_sf` is in common module, in [line 162](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/b2a3509e63a834f8bff3f45de74fcd58baf2c6a5/src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm#L162)